# What options should be added to remove axis overlay by plot?

Tags: highcharts, clip

I'm using highstock navigator and facing the issue that some series info is not rendered properly since it's overlaying everything on the chart area.
Steps To Reproduce:

1. Open the page with the timerange set
2. Change "from" or "to" values to get fetch new data from the BE
3. Zoom using range selector or navigator, so the amount of values for the plot would be little.
4. Observe overlaying.

[image]

Versions:
"highcharts": "^8.2.2",
"highcharts-react-official": "^3.0.0",

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts/highstock'

export default {
  navigator: {
    enabled: true,
    series: {
      dataGrouping: {
        enabled: true,
        groupPixelWidth: 2,
      },
    },
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      dataGrouping: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      showInNavigator: true,
      animation: false,
      states: {
        inactive: {
          opacity: 1,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  rangeSelector: {
    buttons: [
      {
        type: 'second',
        count: 30,
        text: '30s',
      },
      {
        type: 'minute',
        count: 1,
        text: '1m',
      },
      {
        type: 'minute',
        count: 5,
        text: '5m',
      },
      {
        type: 'minute',
        count: 15,
        text: '15m',
      },
      {
        type: 'hour',
        count: 1,
        text: '1h',
      },
      {
        type: 'day',
        count: 1,
        text: '1d',
      },
      {
        type: 'week',
        count: 1,
        text: '1w',
      },
      {
        type: 'month',
        count: 1,
        text: '1M',
      },
      {
        type: 'all',
        text: 'All',
      },
    ],
    inputEnabled: false,
    allButtonsEnabled: true,
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
  },
} as Highcharts.Options

// Result options are built here
const chartOptions = {
    ...defaultHighchartOptions,
    ...options,
    yAxis,
    series: timeSeriesData,
    time: {
      useUTC: false,
    },
  }
```

See the screenshots with the options I have as the result before rendering chart:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you reproduce your case with the sample data on some online editor?